# Store query results to CSV over FTP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a CSV file from the SQL query results. Till now i have been using the local storage to store the file.
But now i want to open a ftp connection and open the file and write my chnages.

My code is as follow:

```
$ftp_server = "subdomain.domain.com";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'uN@m3', '$pWd00');

$filename = 'ftp://uN@m3:$pWd00@subdomain.domain.com.com:21/db_user_export_'.time().'.csv';       //Change this to FTP URL of the server where File is going to be placed

function populateCSVforRightNowDatabase(){

global $database, $filename, $queryInterval, $logger;
/*My Query*/

if($resultSet->load()) {

    // Create or Overwrite file
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

    // Write the spreadsheet column titles / labels
    fputcsv($handle, array( /*columns*/));

    foreach($resultSet as $result) {
        fputcsv($handle, array(/*Results*/));
    }
} else {
        $message = "Load Error: " . $resultSet->getLoadError();
        $logger->error($message);
}
// Finish writing the csv
fclose($handle);
```

}

Comment: what seems to be the problem? what is your question?

Comment: i can not create file on ftp .. though i am able to create on local

Comment: can you provide more details? any errors?

Comment: you can't us `fopen` for ftp. you have to use ftp functions.

Comment: The PHP streams layer should be able to handle this, [the docs seem to indicate you can use an ftp path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with `fopen`.  VJ, do you get any error output?  Please add it to your question.

Comment: Are you sure you can append to files via ftp? I've never seen that before in standard ftp clients - it's always a  whole-file transferrer.

Comment: @MarcB, You can indeed, I just tested it locally - PHP implements it via the STOR/APPE commands.

Comment: @BradKoch so shall i first create a file on local and transfer it via ftp rather than opening a file via ftp and writing to it ?

Comment: @V.J. You can do either. As others have suggested, there are ftp_ functions for transferring files, but fopen should work for you as well.  If you're stuck, please give us error output/an update of where you're at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen` supports multiple [read/write modes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).  However, the mode you selected, `w+`, is read/write mode, which is not supported by FTP.  Barring other errors, using `w` or `a` instead should work.